# Delete a paragraph that starts with specific word from selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to delete a paragraph that starts with string "Page:" from the selection

Here is the sample text that I have:

> Page: 28
>
> Page: 44 contains a lot of example. But look up here for the detailed
>   explanation. This may go for more than one, two or three lines. This
>   totally depends upon the length of the text
>
> Date: 10 Jan 2018
>
> Some text goes here with Page: 108
>
> I’ve some more text here
>
> Few more
>
> Final Text
>
> Page: 208
>
> This is the end

The code I have so far:

```
Sub DelPara()

    Dim para As Paragraph

    With Selection.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "[^13^11]Page:"
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute
        If (Selection.Range.Find = True) Then
            para.Range.Delete
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

The output should be

> Date: 10 Jan 2018
>
> Some text goes here with Page: 108
>
> I’ve some more text here
>
> Few more
>
> Final Text
>
> This is the end

Comment: Am I correct in interpreting that what you need is code that finds *all* instances in the current selection, not just the first one?

Comment: As you're new to the site: It's customary to mark the contribution that best answers your question as "the answer" by clicking the checkmark at its left. Later, when you've accumulated enough "points" on the site, you'll also be able to *upvote* any contribuion (question and/or answer) you find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will search all instances of the search term in the current selection and delete the search term plus the entire paragraph in which the end of the term is located.

The key to this is using two `Range` objects: one for the original Range to be searched (the selection), the other for the actual search. In this way, the range that performs the actual search can be extended from the end of the last successful search to the end of the original range.

```
Sub DelPara()
    Dim rngFind As Word.Range, rngSel As Word.Range
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    Set rngSel = Selection.Range
    Set rngFind = rngSel.Duplicate

    With rngFind.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .text = "[^13^11]Page:"
        .Forward = True
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    bFound = rngFind.Find.Execute
    Do While bFound
        rngFind.End = rngFind.paragraphs.Last.Range.End
        rngFind.Delete
        rngFind.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        rngFind.End = rngSel.End
        bFound = rngFind.Find.Execute
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the details. Works perfect! :-)

Comment: I've a little problem. After the code gets executed, the selection goes off. Is there anyway to keep the selection 'on'?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace with:

```
Find = ^13Page:[!^13]{1,}
Replace = nothing
```

No code required. At most, you might need to insert an empty paragraph at the beginning of the document and delete it afterwards - but then only if the first para starts with 'Page:'. Nevertheless, as a macro:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  .InsertBefore vbCr
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "^13Page:[!^13]{1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  .Characters.First = vbNullString
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you want to process only the selected range, change 'ActiveDocument' to 'Selection'.

Comment: I've a little problem. After the code gets executed, the selection goes off. Is there anyway to keep the selection 'on'?

Comment: The code I posted has no effect at all on the selection unless what is selected includes content the macro deletes. If whatever is selected is entirely within that range, the selection collapses to the start of what was deleted; otherwise, the selection's span is reduced to whatever's left after the deletion.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it